# How to count by months with relations

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I'm facing a Doctrine/SQL issue !

I have a `Device` entity an a `DeviceStatusHistory` entity with a `Many-to-Many` relation.

The `DeviceStatusHistory` entity has 4 properties : `id`, `device`, `status`, `dateAdd`.

The `Device` entity has : `id`, `dateAdd`, `...`

I want to have, for each 12 past months, the COUNT of devices by the last status (on the last day of month).

I've tried several Mysql requests in PhpMyAdmin, starting by `DeviceStatusHistory' side or by`Device` side, but I can't manage to get the result I want.

I tried, for example :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(dsh.device_id)) total_devices
     , dsh.status 
  FROM device_status_history dsh 
 WHERE dsh.status IN ('free', 'assigned', 'deployed', 'given_back', 'to_be_recycled', 'winterized', 'under_repair', 'at_after_sale') 
   AND dsh.date_add <= LAST_DAY(NOW())      
 GROUP 
    BY dsh.status
```

it returns:

```
+---------------+--------------+
| total_devices |    status    |
+---------------+--------------+
|             1 | assigned     |
|          1585 | deployed     |
|            68 | free         |
|             2 | given_back   |
|             1 | under_repair |
+---------------+--------------+
```

If I add a `DeviceStatusHistory` for a 'deployed' `Device` with status 'given_back', I should get

```
+---------------+--------------+
| total_devices |    status    |
+---------------+--------------+
|             1 | assigned     |
|          1584 | deployed     |
|            68 | free         |
|             3 | given_back   |
|             1 | under_repair |
+---------------+--------------+
```

But it returns :

```
+---------------+--------------+
| total_devices |    status    |
+---------------+--------------+
|             1 | assigned     |
|          1585 | deployed     |
|            68 | free         |
|             3 | given_back   |
|             1 | under_repair |
+---------------+--------------+
```

We can see we have the device counted twice but I want to count it only once.

How can I achieve this for the past 12 months in SQL query or Doctrine query in Symfony

Comment: I'm a bit confused. if you start with 1585  'deployed'  and add one 'given_back'. Why do expect to have 1584 'deployed'

Comment: Hi Gabriel. Because I only want the last device status for the month (or before if it didn't change). So, I should have a "transfert" from 'deployed' to 'given_back'

Comment: You want to have the latest for each month ? or the latest for the whole year ?
You can use an analytical function like LAST_VALUE

Comment: The aim is to get a stacked bar graphic, with, for each month, the number of devices by status. As Devices may change status multiple times a month, I want the last status of the month (for each month and for each device). I didn't know LAST_VALUE, i'm gonna take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
WITH last_12_month_EndIntervals AS 
(
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as StartInterval,LAST_DAY(NOW()) as EndInterval UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 MONTH),DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 3 MONTH),DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 4 MONTH),DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 5 MONTH),DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 4 MONTH) UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 6 MONTH),DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 5 MONTH) UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 MONTH),DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 8 MONTH),DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 MONTH) UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 9 MONTH),DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 8 MONTH) UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 10 MONTH),DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 9 MONTH) UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 11 MONTH),DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 10 MONTH) UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 12 MONTH),DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 11 MONTH) 
), Lastest_Status_past_12_months AS (
select DISTINCT lst.StartInterval
    ,dsh.device_id
    ,LAST_VALUE(dsh.status) OVER (PARTITION BY lst.StartInterval,dsh.device_id 
                                    ORDER BY dsh.dateAdd ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PREECEDING 
                                    AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as LatestStatus
FROM last_12_month_EndIntervals lst
LEFT JOIN DeviceStatusHistory dsh ON (dsh.DateAdd > lst.StartInterval and dsh.DateAdd <= lst.EndInterval)
WHERE dsh.status IN ('free', 'assigned', 'deployed', 'given_back', 'to_be_recycled', 'winterized', 'under_repair', 'at_after_sale') 
)
SELECT StartInterval
    ,status
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT(device_id)) total_devices  
  FROM Lastest_Status_past_12_months  
GROUP BY StartInterval,status
```

If you are having issue create a [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) with your table structure and input data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time. Unfortunately, i'm not using Mysql 8 and I can't use "WITH" function.

Comment: for this purpose CTE are just more readable derived tables. So just use it like that instead.